# How to inspect package version installed in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I run:

```
RUN pip install requests pandas sqlalchemy psycopg2
```

But how can I find the versions of these packages ? Is there some command line like :

```
pip list
```

Comment: Yes, there is a `pip list` command. See the output of `pip help` and `pip help list` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should always do version pinning, so specify the exact version number when you install a package (with any package manager) to have reproducable builds otherwise a package might have breaking changes and break your app on the next build.